# Como acesso os elementos dentro de um elemento dinamico com jquery

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde.

Tenho  uma dúvida.
Utilizei o comando load (do jquery) pra carregar uma pagina, e dentro da mesma possui um form.
Quando este form for processado, ele deverá alterar a div que está na mesma hierarquia do load.

Eu estou tentando fazer assim:

```
$("#conteudo").on('form[name=formCadastraQuadra]').submit(function(){

   //como eu acesso os elements inputs deste cara?

});
```

Muito obrigado

Comment: Testa com `$("#conteudo").on('submit', 'form[name=formCadastraQuadra]', function(){`

Comment: Muito obrigado.
Mas como eu acesso os elements com o (each)

  `$(this).each('input', function(i, obj){
   alert(obj);
  });`

Comment: Quais elementos? os elementos do form? podes ser mais claro?

Comment: Se percebo bem queres `$(this).find('input').each(...`

Answer (score 1):

Quando usas um evento delegado o `this` dentro da callback é o elemento a que o evento foi delegado. Assim o `this` será a form e para ir buscar os inputs descendentes dessa form podes usar o [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). Algo assim:

```
$("#conteudo").on('submit', 'form[name=formCadastraQuadra]', function(){
    $(this).find('input').each(function(i, el){
        // aqui o "el" e o `this` corresponde ao elemento iterado
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio,